# Pass parameters to stored procedure for paginated report column selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, powerbi-paginated-reports

I want to create a paginated report in Power BI using stored procedure with parameters.

These parameters are column names, cols for number of columns selected and other parameters.

For example, I have many columns in my view called `vw_Sales`, all I want my paginated report to do is whenever any columns are selected then it should return the values of the columns selected.

How can I write a stored procedure for paginated report?
Below statement is what I have written but not sure if this way works or is there a better way?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_pocSalesReport] 
    (@BrandName varchar(max),
     @StoreName varchar(max),
     @Cols varchar(max),
     @pivot varchar(max),
     @DateFrom varchar(max),
     @DateTo varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)

    SELECT 
        'X' as filename,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('item_Nbr', @Cols) > 0 THEN 'item_Nbr' ELSE 'hide' END AS Col1Name,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('item_Nbr', @Cols) > 0 THEN item_Nbr ELSE '' END AS Col1Value,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('brand_id', @Cols) > 0 THEN 'brand_id' ELSE 'hide' END AS Col2Name,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('brand_id', @Cols) > 0 THEN brand_id ELSE '' END AS Col2Value,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('brand_name', @Cols) > 0 THEN 'brand_name' ELSE 'hide' END AS Col3Name,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('brand_name', @Cols) > 0 THEN brand_name ELSE 'NA' END AS Col3Value,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('item_create_date', @Cols) > 0 THEN 'item_create_date' ELSE 'hide' END AS Col4Name,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('item_create_date', @Cols) > 0 THEN [item_create_date] ELSE '01/01/2000' END AS Col4Value,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Store_Name', @Cols) > 0 THEN 'Store Name' ELSE 'hide' END AS Col5Name,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Store_Name', @Cols) > 0 THEN [Store_Name] ELSE 'NA' END AS Col5Value,
        CASE WHEN @pivot = 'Day_Of_Week' THEN 'Day_Of_Week_Number' WHEN @pivot = 'Month' THEN 'Month_Number' ELSE 'hide' END AS Col8Name,
        CASE WHEN @pivot = 'Day_Of_Week' THEN [Day_Of_Week_Number] WHEN @pivot = 'Month' THEN [Month_Number] ELSE '0'END AS Col8Value,
        CASE WHEN @pivot = 'Day_Of_Week' THEN 'Day_Of_Week' WHEN @pivot = 'Month' THEN 'Month'  ELSE 'hide' END AS Col7Name,
        CASE WHEN @pivot = 'Day_Of_Week' THEN [Day_Of_Week] WHEN @pivot = 'Month' THEN [Month] ELSE 'NA' END AS Col7Value,
        AVG([Avg_Price]) AS [Avg_Price],
        SUM([Sales]) AS [SALES],
        SUM(Qty) AS [QTY]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[vw_Sales] AS s
    WHERE       
        s.item_create_date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
        AND s.[brand_name] IN (SELECT value 
                               FROM STRING_SPLIT(@BrandName, ',') 
                               WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '')
        AND s.[Store_Name] IN (SELECT value 
                               FROM STRING_SPLIT(@StoreName, ',') 
                               WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '')
    GROUP BY
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('item_Nbr', @Cols) > 0 THEN item_Nbr ELSE '' END,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('brand_id', @Cols) > 0 THEN brand_id ELSE '' END,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('brand_name', @Cols) > 0 THEN [brand_name] ELSE 'NA' END,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('item_create_date', @Cols) > 0 THEN [item_create_date] ELSE '01/01/2000' END,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Store_Name', @Cols) > 0 THEN [Store_Name] ELSE 'NA' END,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Day_Of_Week', @pivot) > 0 THEN [Day_Of_Week] ELSE 'NA' END,
        CASE WHEN @pivot = 'Day_Of_Week' THEN [Day_Of_Week_Number] WHEN @pivot = 'Month' THEN [Month_Number] ELSE '0' END,
        CASE WHEN @pivot = 'Day_Of_Week' THEN [Day_Of_Week] WHEN @pivot = 'Month' THEN [Month] ELSE 'NA' END
END
```

Comment: Why not control the visibility of the column within SSRS itself? Columns have a Hidden property. It looks like you're overly complicating things by trying to handle some of this in your SQL.

Comment: @Larnu - how do I do this? I have lot of Columns in the view and it is not every columns is needed. Please can you help me. I'm new to paginated reports

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also: why on earth do you use `nvarchar(max)` datatype for your date parameters (`@DateFrom`, `@DateTo`)? You should always use the *most appropriate* datatype - which is `DATE` (or `DATETIME2(n)`, if you also need the time component) - but most certainly **not** `nvarchar(max)` .... even for your string-based parameters, it's at least questionable if you really need **2 GB** of parameter space for each - I'd recommend to use a more appropriate, more realistic length

Comment: I suggest you start over with the "primary parameters" (defined using appropriate datatypes) after reading erland's discussion of [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). Get that working and then attempt to add pagination.